# Reading orc does not trigger projection pushdown and predicate push down

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, avro, orc

I have a fileA in orc with the following format

```
key
    id_1
    id_2
value
    value_1
     ....
    value_30
```

If I use the following config:

```
'spark.sql.orc.filterPushdown'                : true
```

And my code looks like this:

```scala
val filter_A = fileA_DF
  .filter(fileA_DF("value.value_1") > lit(some_value))
  .select("key.id_")
```

the size of the file read will be the same as

```scala
val filter_A = fileA_DF
  .filter(fileA_DF("value.value_1") > lit(some_value))
  .select("*")
```

Shouldn't spark only

1. predicate pushdown - read files and stripes that satisfy the filter
2. projection pushdown - read columns that we are used?

I also checked with similar sized avro file and found no improvement in selection speed

Am i measuring orc the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at let's take the following reproducible example:

```scala
val df = Seq(
  ((1,1),(2,2)),
  ((1,1),(2,2)),
  ((1,1),(2,2))
).toDF("key", "value")

val keySchema = "struct<id_1:int,id_2:int>"
val valueSchema = "struct<value_1:int,value_2:int>"

val input = df.select(col("key").cast(keySchema), col("value").cast(valueSchema))

scala> input.show
+------+------+
|   key| value|
+------+------+
|{1, 1}|{2, 2}|
|{1, 1}|{2, 2}|
|{1, 1}|{2, 2}|
+------+------+

input.write.mode("overwrite").orc("myFile.orc")
```

If we now read this file as with the filters that you apply and use the `explain` method, we see the following:

```scala
val output = spark.read.orc("myFile.orc")
  .filter(col("key.id_1") > lit(1))
  .select("key.id_1")
  .explain

scala> output.explain
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [key#68.id_1 AS id_1#73]
+- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(value#69) AND (value#69.value_1 > 1))
   +- FileScan orc [key#68,value#69] Batched: false, DataFilters: [isnotnull(value#69), (value#69.value_1 > 1)], Format: ORC, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/C:/Users/(C)KurtHoman/myFile.orc], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(value), GreaterThan(value.value_1,1)], ReadSchema: struct<key:struct<id_1:int>,value:struct<value_1:int>>
```

We see that there are some `DataFilters`/`PushedFilters` at work, so predicate pushdown is working. If you want to really avoid to read full files, you need to make sure your input file is properly partitioned. Some more info about those filters [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75315906/15405732).

Now, we do see indeed that both the `key` and the `value` column are being read in, but that is because a `PushedFilter` alone does not guarantee that you absolutely don't read in any value where the filter predicate is false, it just applies a prefilter on the file-level (more info in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75319818/15405732)). So we will actually have to apply that filter in our Spark DAG as well (which you see in the output of `explain`).

So, to wrap it up:

- Your filter predicates are being pushed down. If you want full files not to be read, make sure to partition your file accordingly before reading it in.
- In this case, both your `key` and `value` columns have to be read in. This is because your filter operation requires the `value` column and the final column you're interested in is the `key` column and because the `PushedFilter` alone does not guarantee your predicate to be true.

Comment: does projection pushdown not work for nested column
I thought each column inside `key` and `value` is store in a separate columns, i do need both key and value, but only one value and one key out of the 30 values and two keys
`{
  "deleted": null,
  "expires": -1,
  "value": {
    "value_1": "SUCCESS"
  },
  "operation": "UPSERT",
  "key": {
    "id": 15439231234001,
    "id2": "69312312316"
  },
  "timestamp": 1683213123676914184
}`

Comment: Correct, a column of struct elements is still regarded as a single column. ORC, like parquet, are columnar stores. These store column data contiguously, but the nested fields are not regarded as different columns. If you want to have the power of projection pushdown, you would have to change the schema of your data.